# How to delete sequential duplicate rows with unique identifier?

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I have the following table which is for collecting information for products I'm interested in.

```
CREATE TABLE priceinfo (
    date TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    sku INTEGER,
    price REAL,
    media TEXT,
    url TEXT
);
```

How do I delete entries from the database which has multiple sequential rows of duplicate data with different dates? Sample is data below. I want to keep entries as they change just not entries that are the same day after day.

```
1 2019-12-10    Product1    123456789   25.99   Blu-ray https://www.example.com
2 2019-12-11    Product1    123456789   21.59   Blu-ray https://www.example.com
3 2019-12-12    Product1    123456789   21.59   Blu-ray https://www.example.com
4 2019-12-13    Product1    123456789   21.59   Blu-ray https://www.example.com
5 2019-12-14    Product1    123456789   20.89   Blu-ray https://www.example.com
6 2019-12-15    Product1    123456789   21.59   Blu-ray https://www.example.com
```

In the example, I would want rows #1, #2, #5, and #6 to persist but #3 and #4 to be deleted since no information except the date changes in those two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates have no duplicates, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
             lag(date) over (partition by title, sku, price, media, url order by date) as prev_date2
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date is null or prev_date <> prev_date2;
```

EDIT:

Assuming the dates are unique, you can use the following logic:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
                   lag(date) over (partition by title, sku, price, media, url order by date) as prev_date2
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_date is null or prev_date <> prev_date2
     )
delete from t
    where t.date in (select cte.date from cte);
```

Comment: Say in my example i have product #1, product #2, etc. Would your SQL only affect a specific product or will it affect all products with the same date?

Comment: You just change where prev_date is null or prev_date <> prev_date2; with where prev_date2 is null; and Gordon answer will work as your example

Comment: How would I go about wrapping this in a DELETE statement? I can't seem to find any delete examples with as complicated of SQL as this so the ```DELETE FROM priceinfo WHERE EXISTS (<query above>);``` or similar examples don't work.

Comment: @ktBonefish . . . If you want this *per product* then you want to partition by that column.

Comment: I see @GordonLinoff. Thanks